# Job Title Suggestions

Tags: title

I work in the U.S. branch of a larger company based in Europe. The office I work in is very small, 2-3 employees who handle orders, billing, etc. Then 2-3 managers, an office manager, e-commerce manager, national sales manager and then the president of branch. I've been with the company over a year as a executive sales assistant but recently have been given the green light for a promotion. So now I'm trying to find the best job title fit for what I do and it's been a challenge since I've been used as a jack of all trades since being here. Here is a list of the types of things I've been responsible for:

Event planning: managing all aspects of trade shows (pre-pandemic)

Managing specialized projects for certain clients.

Graphics Design: creating and editing promotional material, product photography, photo editing, etc.

Managing and distributing sales materials to reps and customers: price lists, promos, freight arrivals, managing the printing and shipping of catalogs, etc.

Customer Service: answer customer emails and phone calls, handle warranty replacements (taking down info, picking, packing, shipping)

Create and manage presentations: create, edit and participate in PowerPoint presentations to client's and internal company presentations.

Along with other tasks: running reports, manage sales documents, etc.

I would like my new title to incorporate the graphic design elements of what I do along with the sales and project management. The title I keep coming back to is Project Manager but most of the information I see online says a project manager manages a team, where this would only be me for the foreseeable future. If anyone can suggest other titles that might cover all of the responsibilities I manage, I would greatly appreciate the suggestions.

Comment: "but recently have been given the green light for a promotion."  Does your company let you decide the position that you are promoted to?

Comment: i reckon you couldf get away with "Project Manager"

Comment: [Real questions have answers, not just ideas or suggestions.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)

Comment: Also, a quick grammatical point: apostrophes shouldn't be used to make words plural. You can see [here](https://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/apostro.asp), for example, for more information on the correct way to use apostrophes.

Answer (score 1):

I can not answer your question for your today's position. But probably you should take in consideration to manage your career. Having the opportunity to decide upon your job title is rare.

If I where in your position, I would choose a title according to where I want to advance to in the next 5 years and do that advancement. Maybe not picking a seniority yet, but something simple like "Digital Arts Manager" or "Managing Digital Artist". Years later a "Senior", "Director" or "President" could be added.

Managemnt job title's are considered obsolete in modern culture work environments, because the optimal organization would not need a manager, but be administered and lead from the base by passionate and motivated staff.

Comment: Seek the Job Title for the Job you want, not the Job you have. Even if you are able to get one word, this will help your career progression and development.